# How to point a single code base to multiple SVN projects

Tags: svn

The organisation is looking at moving from Visual Source Safe to Subversion.  The current approach in VSS uses the same one local Netbeans project to handle the dev, qa and release code, with changes being uploaded from the local project (say P:\test) to the appropriate VSS project (e.g. dev).  When looking online I can see plenty of resources describing pointing SVN towards a shared code base e.g. [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tortoisesvn-and-subversion-cookbook-part-4-sharing-common-code/), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894961/svn-with-multiple-projects-and-single-solution), but this, as with the others, seems to be sharing resources between multiple projects, rather than having a single code base point to multiple projects on the repository.

My gut feeling is that it would be better to have each project locally (i.e. dev, qa and release) point to a particular repository, and copying the files that need moved from say dev to qa, rather than trying to replicate the VSS approach of one local project being used to hold multiple repository code bases.  Any opinions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's something CollabNet, Inc., the original sponsor of Subversion, put together.  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion does not support copying files between repositories at all. Maintaining 3 repositories for the same project will be a descent into madness.

Nor do you want to have "multiple codebases" - it's all one codebase, you just have to have a clear process to move your changes from dev, to qa, to release. For that, you want a combination of tags & branches. With regular merges of changes. The exact implementation will come down to how you manage the development of your application, and that may have to change some. Because you will have to un-learn everything that you've learned in working with VSS, because VSS...well, it sucks.

With the following assumptions:

- All developers work in a common codebase during active development
- You have a method by which to say "OK, what we have here is ready for QA testing"
- You have a need to continue development while also fixing bugs for what's in QA
- Once something goes to production, you can't change what's in production without going through your whole process (if you don't have this, you'll have a mess someday)

I would recommend the following:

1. Create the "traditional" trunk/branches/tags structure as described [in the  manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html). All developers check out from trunk for regular development work. Really, read this entire chapter of the manual (twice), as it's a longer, more detailed version of what I'm laying out here.
2. When you decide that it's time to push a release to QA, create a branch by copying the trunk to a directory under `branches`. How you name this is up to you, but be clear and consistent. For example, if you're branching for a release to be named 4.2, maybe name it `QA-4.2` (and the next time you branch for 4.3, name it `QA-4.3` and so on).
3. If(When) you find bugs in your QA testing, you fix them as patches against the `QA-4.2` branch. Whoever is taking care of this will need to check out a second working copy to make these changes and commit them to the branch.
4. Periodically merge the patches you made in the QA branch **back** to the trunk. Otherwise those bugs you fixed in 4.2 will come right back in 4.3.
5. When your code in QA has passed all testing and is blessed for production, create a tag by copying your QA branch into the `tags` directory. You'll probably want to be consistent with what you were doing in QA, with a name of `tags/4.2-RELEASE` or something close to that. And then release your new version.
6. Now is probably the time to use `svn merge --reintegrate` on your branch, then maybe delete the branch. The code's been released, we're moving on to the next version now.
7. What's in the `tags` directory **does not get changed**. If someone finds a bug in production, you work on it just like any new development. Otherwise those changes won't find their way back to trunk (unless someone is watching **really** carefully) and the bug will comeback.

How the Subversion project themselves [create & maintain their release branches](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/community-guide/releasing.html#release-branches) may be informative as well.